# Add conditional Joi schema

Tags: node.js, joi

Ok I give up...

How do I make the `selectorSettings` only appear when `selectorStrategy` is set to `tournament`?

```
selectorStrategy: joi.string().valid(['tournament',  'roulette']).default('tournament'),
selectorSettings: joi.any().when('selectorStrategy', { 
  is: 'tournament',
  then: joi.object().keys({
     tournamentSize: joi.number().integer().default(2),
     baseWeight: joi.number().integer().default(1)
   })
 })
```

I have `stripUnknown: true` set in my options. My expectations are that if I pass:

```
 selectorStrategy: 'roulette',
 selectorSettings: { tournamentSize: 3 }
```

I will get:

```
selectorStrategy: 'roulette'
```

And If I do:

```
selectorStrategy: 'tournament'
```

I will get:

```
 selectorStrategy: 'tournament',
 selectorSettings: { tournamentSize: 2, baseWeight: 1 }
```

Comment: pretty sure you cant do that like that. you need to do the if statement in your code and add the sub scheme if it matches your condition

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set a `selectorSettings` default, and conditionally strip it out based on the value of `selectorStrategy`.

Let's walk through your two use cases.

### Removing a key based on sibling value

```
const thing = {
  selectorStrategy: 'roulette',
  selectorSettings: { tournamentSize: 3 },
};

joi.validate(thing, schema, { stripUnknown: true} );
```

`selectorSettings` won't be removed by the `stripUnknown` option, because the key is not unknown - it's in your schema.

We need to explicitly strip it out based on the value of `selectorStrategy`:

```
.when('selectorStrategy', {
  is: 'tournament',
  otherwise: joi.strip(),
}),
```

### Adding / validating keys based on sibling value

```
const thing = { 
  selectorStrategy: 'tournament'
};

joi.validate(thing, schema);
```

The code is not setting a default for the `selectorSettings` key itself, only its properties. Since `selectorSettings` is not required, the validation passes.

We need to set a default:

```
selectorSettings: joi
  .object()
  .default({ tournamentSize: 2, baseWeight: 1 })
```

---

Modified code that handles both cases would look like this:

```
const joi = require('joi');

const schema = {
  selectorStrategy: joi
    .string()
    .valid(['tournament', 'roulette'])
    .default('tournament'),
  selectorSettings: joi
    .object()
    .default({ tournamentSize: 2, baseWeight: 1 })
    .keys({
      tournamentSize: joi
        .number()
        .integer()
        .default(2),
      baseWeight: joi
        .number()
        .integer()
        .default(1),
    })
    .when('selectorStrategy', {
      is: 'tournament',
      otherwise: joi.strip(),
    }),
};
```

### Examples

```
// should remove settings when not a tournament
var thing = {
  selectorStrategy: 'roulette',
  selectorSettings: { tournamentSize: 3 },
};

// returns
{
  "selectorStrategy": "roulette"
}
```

.

```
// should insert default settings
var thing = {
  selectorStrategy: 'tournament'
};

// returns
{
  "selectorStrategy": "tournament",
  "selectorSettings": {
    "tournamentSize": 2,
    "baseWeight": 1
  }
}
```

.

```
// should add missing baseWeight default
var thing = {
  selectorStrategy: 'tournament',
  selectorSettings: { tournamentSize: 5 } 
};

// returns
{
  "selectorStrategy": "tournament",
  "selectorSettings": {
    "tournamentSize": 5,
    "baseWeight": 1
  }
}
```